# Play mp3 at percentage of volume relative to system volume

Tags: java, android

Is there a way in Android to play an mp3 file inside a "when" condition to play the mp3 at a defined volume relative to what the system volume is set to, in Java?

For example set playback to 40% which should be 40% of whatever the system volume is at?

The reason I need this is because if I set it to 40%, then this 40% will be louder as the system volume increases. I'd like it to be 40% of the system volume.